# Kick Command Is Giving Errors

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

My kick command is below:

````
   @bot.command()
   async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *,reason=None):
      d = datetime.datetime.now()
      channel = bot.get_channel(556058910566514688)
      embed=discord.Embed(title='**Kicked By:** {}# 
     {}'.format(ctx.message.author.name, 
             ctx.message.author.discriminator), colour=discord.Colour(0x7ed321), description='**Reason:** {} \n **Time:** {}/{}/{}'.format(reason, d.year, d.month, d.day))
embed.set_author(name='{}#{}'.format(member.name, member.discriminator), url="https://discordapp.com", icon_url='{}'.format(member.avatar_url, member.name, member.discriminator))
embed.set_thumbnail(url="{}".format(ctx.message.author.avatar_url))
role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Retired Staff")
if ctx.message.author.top_role < role:
        await ctx.send('```Only staff Can kick anyone```')
elif reason is None:
    await ctx.send('You can\'t kick anyone without a reason')
elif ctx.message.author.top_role > role:
    if ctx.message.author.top_role < member.top_role:
        await ctx.send('```You can\'t ban a staff member higher than you```')
    else:
        if ctx.message.author.top_role > member.top_role:
            await member.kick()
            await channel.send(embed=embed)
````

**Error:**

```
   Ignoring exception in on_command_error
       Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "C:\Users\BKhushi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-3 
    2\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 64, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
     File "C:\Users\BKhushi\Desktop\gg\Discordgang.py", line 42, in kick
       await member.kick()
  File "C:\Users\BKhushi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36- 
    32\lib\site-packages\discord\member.py", line 433, in kick
    await self.guild.kick(self, reason=reason)
  File "C:\Users\BKhushi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\guild.py", line 1268, in kick
    await self._state.http.kick(user.id, self.id, reason=reason)
  File "C:\Users\BKhushi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 210, in request
    raise Forbidden(r, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: FORBIDDEN (status code: 403): Missing Permissions

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\BKhushi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 227, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\BKhushi\Desktop\gg\Discordgang.py", line 96, in on_command_error
    raise error
  File "C:\Users\BKhushi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 814, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\BKhushi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 682, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\BKhushi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 73, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: Forbidden: FORBIDDEN (status code: 403): Missing Permissions
```

i don't know wheres the error wheres the error

Comment: Your bot is missing permissions.  Check `ctx.guild.me.guild_permissions.kick_members`, and make sure the person you're trying to kick is lower inthe hierarchy than the bot that is kicking them (not the member who invoked the command)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bot does not have the permissions necessary to kick the member in question. Make sure your bot has the `KICK_MEMBERS` permission and that your bot can interact with the member (your bot's highest role is above their highest role and the member is not the owner of the guild).