# Ban/Kick In Discord.py error due to "permissions"

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Im creating a bot that can ban and kick users if they dont follow the rules. 
when i execute `!ban @user` it gives the error

```
Ignoring exception in command kick:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 83, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/Daniel/Desktop/DAN/1/8/0/1/PROGRAMMING/LegacyCoding/DiscordVidTutBot/bot.py", line 85, in kick
    await ctx.guild.kick(member, reason=reason)
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\guild.py", line 1627, in kick
    await self._state.http.kick(user.id, self.id, reason=reason)
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 221, in request
    raise Forbidden(r, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 892, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 797, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 92, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

I have been through the developer section of discord and made sure it has all the permissions needed to execute the ban and kick command such as `admin` `kick members` `ban members` and still its not working. does anybody know the cause of this and how i can fix it?

Comment: [Kick Command Is Giving Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55748497/kick-command-is-giving-errors/55755203)

Comment: @furas that does not help as i explained ive given it the correct permissions and it still doesnt work

Comment: error show that you don't have correct permissions. I never used it but first I would check `ctx.guild.me.guild_permissions.kick_members` before line which makes problem. I would also use `print(member, reason)` to check values in other variables. You should also add minimal working code which we could run and see if we also will have the same problem. Without code your question seems useless and probably nobody will even try to resolve it.

Comment: @furas its alright i fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I found a fix for it and it turns out that i was trying to kick a member with higher permissions than the bot had so it would not kick them.